# Using a PHP class which doesn't always exist

Tags: php, class

I'm fairly new to object orientated programming, so bear with me if I've missed something simple, or done something wrong.

I have a set up where the domains class can contain details on a domain name (such as name, expiry, creation date etc.), but can also have a $hosting variable which relates to the hosting account that the domain is tied with. However, not all domains are hosted and are just there waiting to be used, so the hosting object doesn't always exist.

In both domains and hosting I have functions to return the relevant details, so for example:

```
private $accountId;
private $name;
private $created;

public function getAccountId() {    return $this->accountId;        }
public function getName() {     return $this->name;     }
public function getCreated() {  return $this->created;  }
```

So, if I wanted the hosting accounts id from within the domain object (called $domain) I could do:

```
$domain->getHosting()->getId();
```

Hopfully that makes sense!

If there is a hosting account, the ID is returned:
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAccountId() on a non-object in /home/sites/.../file.php on line x`

Is there a way of checking if `$domain->getHosting()` exists to prevent this error?

Many Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a simple error!

Comment: There is a simple way of checking it: `if($domain->getHosting()){$domain->getHosting()->getId();}`. FYI, I put it in comment because I believe there are a more robust and OOP way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have not one type, but two:

```
class Domain {
   ....
}

class HostedDomain extends Domain {
   ...
}
```

Write your code accordingly. `HostedDomain` is the a little bit more specific than `Domain`. It can be used everywhere where `Domain` is fitting plus some extra special places.

You can then check each domain if it is hosted;

```
if ($domain instanceof HostedDomain) {
    ...
}
```

See [*Object inheritance*](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.inheritance.php) and [*Type operators*](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.type.php).

Comment: You have excellently exemplified the benefits of inheritance to a programmer new to Object Oriented Programming in a way that has immediately relevant to him/her! I congratulate you on deeply reading into his question an providing an insightful answer that is more encompassing then the OP requested. I wish I could  give you +5, but you'll only get +1

Comment: Thank you very much @hakre! Appreciate the help, especially when I'm new to oop!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

```
   if(method_exists($domain,'getHosting')){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you really want to check if the class exists:

```
if (class_exists('Domain')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

My PHP is more than a little rusty, but I believe `isset($hosting)` within the domain object would help, either as a method (such as hasHost) in the domain class to check whether the host exists, or just `isset($domain->getHosting())`.  Assuming you don't ever set $hosting if there is no host, isset should do what you want.

Comment: Agreed, but the OPs post included `$domain->getHosting()` so I included it as a possible option.

Answer (score 0):

Just check getHosting exists before using it

```
if (! $domain->getHosting()) {
   $value = $domain->getHosting()->getId();
}
```

Comment: It would return `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Domain::getHosting()`   http://codepad.org/HUkXqlbL

Answer (score 0):

Since your method `getHosting()` returns an object, you should store the value into a temporary variable, check if the variable is empty or not, and if it's not empty you can use it:

```
$hosting = $domain->getHosting();
if (!empty($hosting)) {
    $id = $hosting->getId();
}
```

You have a few choices, other than [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty). You could also use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset), [`is_object()`](http://php.net/is_object), or check if `$hosting != null` - all should provide you with the same logic you would need in this scenario.

This all assumes that the `getHosting()` method exists in the `Domain` class, of course (what some of the other answers address).

Comment: @Baba Whoah, thanks for that catch; I'm so used to doing quick-assignments directly in the conditional statements, I didn't expect it to fail inside a function-call like that! Updated answer, thanks again =]